# PHP OOP design structure

Tags: php, oop

My questions applies to these three example classes I have made up for getting a better understanding of how to use OOP.

```
class Book {
    //not using getters/setters to save some space
    public $name;
    public $numreads;
}

class BookFactory {
    private $db;
    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function getBook($id) {
        $book = new Book();

        $book->name = $db->query("SELECT name FROM books...");

        $booknumreads = new BookNumRead($this->db, $book);
        $book->numreads = $booknumreads->getFromLocal() + $booknumreads->getFromAnotherSource();

        return $book;
    }
}

class BookNumRead {
    private $db;
    private $book;
    public function __construct(Database $db, Book $book) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    public function getFromLocal()
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT ... WHERE name = $book->name");
    }

    public function getFromAnotherSource()
    {
        return API::getNumReadsOfABook($book->name);
    }

    //or just stick with this method in this class
    public function getNumReadsOfBook($name)
    {
        return (
                $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT ... WHERE name = $name")
                +
                API::getNumReadsOfABook($name)
        );
    }
}

//get number of reads of a book
$db = new Database();
$bookfactory = new BookFactory($db);
$book = $bookfactory->getBook(123);
echo $book->getNumReads();
```

1. First of all, is this a good OOP approch?
2. These classes is quite different. Domain vs Value objects? For example, there can be as many Book objects as I need in my application.
   The BookFactory however is like a service in my application, there only needs to be one in my application but I may need this class from many other places in my application,
   should i put it as a object in a ServiceLocator/ServiceContainer?
3. The BookNumRead class could also be put in a ServiceLocator/ServiceContainer, and be used by the getNumReadsOfBook() method without a Book object injected, but that feels like procedural programming?
   Or, as in the example above be iniated by the BookFactory::getBook(), but then I need to pass both a Database (that one BookFactory got injected) and a Book to it, and that feels a little bit
   messy, beacasue it may need other "service" classes like a logger for example. What is best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should separate the DB stuff more from your Models/Services. Use a adapter pattern for the DB stuff and handle all SQL in a separate class. You could make the adapter implementing PDO, MySQLi etc.

Think at a higher, more pragmatic level of your models and services, and hide the implementation details in underlying, universal classes.

Comment: Like everything, this is highly subjective =). I've done a whole bunch of projects in the last 10 years, but I've never been in a situation where we had to change database adapters without also having to change a whole bunch of other stuff.

Comment: So it's always made more sense for us to 'just' use PDO everywhere, and do queries directly.

Comment: As projects grow, maintaining the SQL in a lot of classes becomes more pain. By using a adapter pattern, it could/should look like this: $book->name = $adapter->select('name')->from('books') ...

Comment: And from there on its easy to put everything to a 'higher' level .. a real ORM for example.

Comment: For many that's a desirable pattern, so I'm not disagreeing with you.. I do think it depends on context. For us an ORM would not be desirable. I'd personally avoid it except for the stuff that's the most simple / rapid prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making BookNumRead a property of Book.

Furthermore, in the `__construct()` function of Book, you could consider running a query to get all the book details.

If you change:

```
class Book {
    //not using getters/setters to save some space
    public $name;
    public $numreads;
}
```

to:

```
class Book {
    //not using getters/setters to save some space
    public $name;
    public $numreads;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT ... WHERE name = $book->name");
        // Use return value to get number of times book is read...
        $this->numreads=$countFromDatabase;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a `= new Book($id);` and you will automatically get the number of times it was read.

Based on this, you could also get the name (and any other important details) from the database based on the ID automatically